# 'Set like' behaviour of dict.items() for non hashable values

Tags: python, dictionary, set

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

The documentation says:

> If all values are hashable, so that (key, value) pairs are unique and hashable, then the items view is also set-like.

However non-hashable items (lists) do seem to support 'set-like' operations:

```py
> {1:2, 3:4}.items() >= {1:2}.items()
True
> {1:[2], 3:4}.items() >= {1:[2]}.items()
True
> set({1:[2], 3:4}.items())
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Why does this work? Can this behavior be relied upon to work correctly? I have not found a list that does not behave.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Dict items support set-like operations, yes, but they are not sets. You cannot have anything unhashable in a set (and tuple with a list inside items is obviuosly unhashable). You can, of course, have unhashable values in a dictionary, and this does not restirct "set-like" operations. Efficiency differs, of course: `dict.items` does never use any hashes, so your `>=` is executed by a bunch of comparisons without previous hash-based dispatch. You can define your class with `print`s in `__hash__` and `__eq__` to see what happens exactly.

Comment: https://tio.run/##zZDBaoQwEIbveYq5bQIi6F6KoNTjXnrptSDWjBjQ6GZisZR9dpuoXS3bB2gOYfLPN/P/ZPi0Ta/PT4OZ59r0HcjSllVbEiGB6obe2F1i7HmvlxvyhIE7UwJKW7bUEmsoCrwWBSds6wB626ARK@iPqkH3FhQpTbbUFfKFCCAXCRi0o9Hw0ttLN7TYobYo76ODcTb8hNeTuGvbhPcKJ0jT1S@cDmGakpotziHHtsw3H9d5la87BWMb@qZfXXdIgMZ3QuumZAQpfEUJ5DwSAcS@iMWNyfig3xh5zE1wGYUfZTsicSEYxT9qfFB3syzLQKpq9QmVxc4BkKXg@O31G14zOTPHUPwY23/7X9HP/y36PH8D

Answer (score 1):

I believe that second of documentation is incorrect. A dictionary's `items` view always behaves like a set, because its contents are unique. We know that's the case because all the keys are unique, and the items are always 2-tuples including a key. The implementation doesn't need to hash the value part of the tuple, hashing the key is enough to efficiently do all the `set` operations.

Comment: Thanks, does this mean the `.items` set operations are only checking the keys? Or are they first checking the keys, and then doing a `==` on the values (instead of a `==` on the hashes of the key value pairs?

Comment: Every dict operation that looks up a key (using its hash) also checks that the entry found matches the key too, since hash collisions are possible. With an items view, I am pretty sure it compares both parts of the tuple (after using only the hash of the key for the initial lookup).

Comment: @EvanBenn you can visualize subset of two dictitems as "set union of keys (hash, then `__eq__` for common elements), followed by `__eq__` comparison of corresponding values - where keys and values are both equal, include this pair into intersection." It's not the same process as for set of tuples: values are not included into hash, because keys already almost form a set.